# Taking LCM in derivative question $\lim_{x\to 1} \left[ \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{3}{1-x^3}\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits

in my mathematics homework. I had a chance to pass through this question:

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \left[ \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{3}{1-x^3}\right]$$

According to my understandings this should be converted into this:

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \left[ (1-x^3) - \frac{3(1-x)}{(1-x)(1-x^3)}\right]$$

Multiplying the denominators of each with the other nominators; as it should be, and a product of them both at the bottom.

But in the notes (answer sheet) that I am referencing to it is provided as

$$\lim_{ x\to 1} [ (x^2 + x + 1) - 3 / [(1-x)(x^2 + x + 1)]]$$

How did that come up? I mean, where did one $(1-x)$ go from denominator? Please help me get the point of the writer.

Reference the notes below, question 3.

http://www.mathcity.org/doku.php?id=viewer&f=http://www.mathcity.org/files/bsc/calculus/ch01/Chap_01_Solutions_Ex_1_2_Calculus

My apologies for bad format, I don't know the formatting of the math equations here! Sorry.

Comment: I think your 2nd equation is wrong. Shouldn't it be $\lim_{x\to 1} \left[ \frac{(1-x^3) - 3(1-x)}{(1-x)(1-x^3)}\right]$?

Comment: Exactly, that was confusing me a bit since in the notes it was presented this way! But when I took the LCM, it became the one proposed in the question. Mine is correct? @draks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^3}\right]=\lim_{x\to 1}\left[\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}\right]$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 1}\left[\frac{1+x+x^2-3}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}\right]=\lim_{x\to 1}\left[\frac{x^2+x-2}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}\right]$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 1}\left[\frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}\right]=-\lim_{x\to 1}\left[\frac{x+2}{1+x+x^2}\right]=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

It is just like LCM of $2$ and $2*3$ is $2*3$.
In your case:

$1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$

therefore LCM is :

$(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$ or $1-x^3$

Comment: Right, just tell me where is the `1-x` that was already present in the denominator? Where did that go?

Comment: Your answer will simplify to that given in the book. However, it is easier to not take repeated common factors, as eventually they cancel out. In the numerator,  $x-1$ is common, which cancels out from the denominator.